# AS400 Java Java program completed with exit code 1

Tags: java, ibm-midrange

Every attempt to run a java program on our AS400 (I5 OS VR4, JVM 1.4.2) result in the same error message:

Java program completed with exit code 1

Any suggestions?

Comment: If it's just a simple hello world app, can you post the code?

Answer (score 1):

Not AS/400 specific but...

All Java programs?  Or a specific java program?

If it's all Java programs - your install of the JVM is corrupted/misconfigured. How are you trying to run the Java programs?

If it's a specific Java program - any logging? error messages? Returning exit code 1 doesn't mean anything other than System.exit(1) was called - for the specific reason it was called (what that return value means, why the program determined it needed to exit, etc.) you'd have to look at the code/talk to the developer.

Comment: It's a simple "hello world" program I wrote. I'm invoking by running the JAVA command and specifying the JAR and class path. No other error messages. I believe the classpath is not the issue since it will report a bad classpath if that is set incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

The link below explains how to run the Hello World program on the 400 to make sure the LICPGM was installed properly. You can use the same as the starting step of your troubleshooting.
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/html/as400/v4r5/ic2924/index.htm?info/java/rzaha/runfirst.htm